# Creating otel Extensions jar with maven not gradle

Tags: open-telemetry, jaeger

I am using opentelemetry-javaagent.jar. I am trying to create extensions to add in -Dotel.javaagent.extensions. The jar file I am creating with is maven. Its not working. On there official site they have used gradle.
Could you help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add your maven.pom file content. It's unclear what is wrong without content